# Sort one column in excel with respect to another

Tags: excel, sorting

I have two excel sheets, the sheet 1 has id and name and that sheet is sorted on the basis of id. The second sheet has the name and other many columns. The second sheet needs to be ordered on the basis of id too. How can I compare these two sheets and order.

Comment: you cannot add the ID also in the second table ? the second table have duplicated row ?

Comment: could you upload a sample

Answer (score 1):

A quick and easy way to do this would be to insert a new column in your second sheet, providing the ID for each name.

Insert a new row and use the `match` function to find the row in the first sheet corresponding to each name, combining this with the `index` function would retrieve the IDs

e.g. `=index('ID col in sheet 1, match('name in sheet 2','name col in sheet 1',0))`

You can then sort all columns using the ID column created in sheet 2

The vlookup function would also be an option if you wanted